# How to run Core PHP App and Codeigniter App Side by Side

Tags: php, codeigniter, inventory

I have an inventory management system written in core php, now i have another enhanced version of the same application written in Codeignter. I want to use these two apps in parallel, Can I run these two applications in single server with under single domain name?

I meant to say i want to run these two apps under same root directory, they use the same database but run independently and have different GUI.

Comment: You'd have to use something like .htaccess to route to each app as needed. You could also let PHP handle the routing by changing your front controller to examine the request and route to each app's original front controller.

Comment: Please clarify, what exactly do you mean by parallel. Do you want access second's instance from within the first's? Or is it do you want that both should run parallely, independent of each other in the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your domain is `xyz.com`

**Create a subdomain like `a.xyz.com`**

It means you are going to create a directory like

```
xyz.com/a
```

within the **folder a**
Run core PHP / Codeigniter and run other in the **root** .
So both apps can use same database